# how to update a control in another updatepanel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have three updatepanels in hierarchy:

```
UpdatePanel1--Root
  UpdatePanelChild1
  UpdatePanelChild2
```

Can I update a control in updatePanel1 on an event of the updatepanel2?

Comment: Thank you Brian Mains. You created more sense in my question.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a big fan of every updatepanel updating all the time - that seems to undo the locality update panels get you.

Another option is to specifically call the .Update() method of the OTHER update panel in your code. For example, suppose you have a button on UppdatePanelChild1 that does some processing and modifies a control in UpdatePanel2:

```
textBoxInsideUpdatePanel2.Text = "Updated!";
UpdatePanel2.Update();
```

Comment: But I want to update only the control which is required, not the whole updatepanel.

Comment: Great answer - I also had to add "UpdateMode = Conditional" on the element to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the easiest way is have `UpdateMode="Always"`; then all update panels update regardless of whichever one triggered the postback.

Comment: But I want to update only the control which is required, not the whole updatepanel.

Comment: The UpdatePanel updates itself; it cannot isolate an updated result to a single control only; so you would have to wrap that control only in an UpdatePanel.  An UpdatePanel in an UpdatePanel can work, so you can leave the other UpdatePanel as is.

Comment: I think it make sense. I will try and let you know.