# binding grid view on button click in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list view with a button for each row:

```
 <td> <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="select" CommandName="view" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("inquiry_id")%>'   onclick="buttonClick"/></td>
```

On click of this button i retrieve the id of the clicked row, set the session with the same id and bind the grid view.This the code behind the button click in list view:

```
ListViewItem item = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as ListViewItem;
    Button butDetails = (Button)item.FindControl("Button2");
    Int64 inquiryID = Convert.ToInt64(butDetails.CommandArgument);
    Session["session_view_id"] = inquiryID;
    this.BindGrid();               
    return;
```

The session is retrieved in bindGrid function. But the problem is gridview is not displayed at first click but on second click it gets displayed but with the data of the previous id clicked.The session is set but while binding the grid it uses old session value. Where am i going wrong to bind the grid?
The code for the bindGrid() function is :

```
 int inquiryID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["session_view_id"]);
   MySqlConnection conn = null;
    try
    {          MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM crm_support_inquiry inner join  crm_inquiry_perticipant on crm_support_inquiry.inquiry_id=?id inner join crm_mailer_types on crm_support_inquiry.mailer_id=crm_mailer_types.mailer_id limit 4", connect);

        using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", inquiryID);
            cmd.Connection = connect;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
           {

               sda.Fill(dt);
                lblComp.Text = dt.Rows[0]["company"].ToString();
                lblCname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["contact_name"].ToString();
              lblEmail.Text = dt.Rows[0]["email"].ToString();
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
           }
        }
```

Comment: Did you check debugging your `BindGrid()` method to see how it gets called?

Comment: (This is not related answer) `Button butDetails = (Button)item.FindControl("Button2");` is not necessary, `Button butDetails = (sender as Button);`

Comment: yes.I debugged.It gets the right value but while displaying it displays data of previous id.

Comment: On button click it gets the right id. And also the session saves the id. When i debbuged the id passed to the gridview was also right but while displaying the gridview it shows the data of previous id. May be binding gets late.

Comment: I would recommend looking into the page life cycle of ASP.NET.
A dirty quick fix could be to do a Response.Redirect to the same page after you have set the session_view_id. This will make the page reload from fresh and since the session_view_id is saved in the session, it will use that when calling the BindGrid method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you checking for IsPostBack in your Page_Load method? You need to wrap your BindGrid call in your Page_Load in an if(!IsPostBack) statement to prevent the Page_Load from initially refreshing the data on postback. This can prevent the changes you are making later on in your event handler.

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

This answer can provide additional info: [How to update page data after event handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780684/how-to-update-page-data-after-event-handling)

Comment: My Listview is inside the update panel content template. Will that affect the postback anyway??

Comment: But the button on click of which the gridview is supposed to be displayed is inside the listview and listview is within the update panel.

Comment: If the grid is not in an update panel it cannot be updated on an asynchronous postback (the type of postback performed by an update panel. You either need to put the grid in the same update panel or in its own. If your are putting it in its own, you can update it by calling GridUpdatePanelName.Update(). See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701338/how-to-update-a-control-in-another-updatepanel

Comment: Thanks ThoBa now its working.I put the grid in another update panel and made UpdateMode="Always". Thank  you so much.