# Labe outside datagridview not updating on datagrid row selected index ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, updatepanel

When the user selects a row in my datagrid view the label outside the datagridview does not update.

Here is my datagridview
[image: Here is what my webpage looks like]

As you can see in visual studio the value of the selected row is captured. However visually it  does not update.

[image: Correct value]

Here is what my datagrid code looks like.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uplPanel"  runat="server" >
            <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:GridView ID="gvInventario" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  AllowSorting="true" ShowFooter="false" DataKeyNames="componente_id, ubicacion_id, proveedor_id"  PageSize="20"
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"
                 CellPadding="3"  AllowColumResize="True" onsorting="grdDetails_Sorting" GridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">    
                <Columns>
```

Here is what the code for the labels outside the grid looks like

```
      <div id="ChangeQuantitySection"  class="menusection">
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Cambiar la cantidad" CssClass="second-menu-title"></asp:Label>  
          <br/>
            <b><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Proveedor:  "></asp:Label></b>
            <asp:Label ID="lblProveedor" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br/>
            <b><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Tipo:  "></asp:Label></b>
            <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br/>
            <b><asp:Label ID="lblQtRequired" runat="server" Text="Cantidad requerida:  "></asp:Label></b>
            <asp:TextBox width="50px" ID="txtQtRequired" runat="server" TextMode="Number" min="0" step="1" Value="0"></asp:TextBox> 
          <br/>
        <asp:Button class="btn btn-primary"  ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Validar" OnClick="Confirm_purchase_order_Click"  />

        </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change UpdateMode="Conditional" to UpdateMode="Always" Thanks to the answer I found here [how to update a control in another updatepanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701338/how-to-update-a-control-in-another-updatepanel)

Answer (score 1):

Check if you use correct lable IDs. Because in your example labels ids are not consistent.  Update the correct labels in your event.

Comment: Yes you are right I pasted the wrong code. I corrected my question

Comment: However this dose not fix my problem as my label still dose not update.